# Direct sum of 3 vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to find some example of 3 subspaces A, B, C of some vector space X, such that $A+B, A+C, B+C$ and $A+B+C$ are all direct sums of X.
Is there any ideas? I tries basis vectors but those are not really working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean for each $x\in X$ there would be unique sums
$$
X = a + b = a + b + c
$$
with $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$.

Which requires $C = V_0 = \{ 0 \}$, which would require $X = A + C = A$. Same for $B$. But then $X = A + B$. We would end up with $X = A = B = C = V_0$ and this is most likely not wanted.